# Restcomm default username and password

Tags: sip-server, mobicents, restcomm

Hi Guys I was trying run mobicents Telestax RestComm, and after I and the "mobicents-media-server\bin\run.bat" and the "Mobicents-RestComm-Jboss-AS7-7.2.2.616\bin\standalone.bat -c standalone-sip.xml"

and both commands ran fine.

and the I tried to access 127.0.0.1:8080/Restcomm-management

but the default login username and password of

```
username : administrator@company.com
password : RestComm
```

won't go through, how do I perhaps add a new admin manually and rectify this problem please help.

Answer (score 2):

@Njabulo Nsibande

If you are having problems logging in with the default password, please try the following steps

- Make sure this is not an issue with your browser. Have you tried another browser?
- Try restarting Restcomm and try to log in again.
- If that still doesn't work, there might be an issue with the downloaded binary. I suggest you download the latest one https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/RestComm/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/
- If you want to reset the password, then, follow the instruction as outlined here: http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-reset-admin-password/

Comment: I did that on and i am using mobicentsAS7-7.2.2.619 now and this is the error i am getting... please check subsequent comment for the log
  '

Comment: ERROR [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.startup.SipStandardContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) An error occured when notifying the servlet org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.Bootstrapper of the event SERVLET_INITIALIZED: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error building SqlSession.
### The error may exist in file://C:\Mobicents-Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.2.2.619\standalone\deployments\restcomm.war\/WEB-INF/sql/accounts.xml
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.net.UnknownHostException: C

Comment: There seem to be a problem with the path you have. Please check and make sure the path mentioned in the error output does exist. file://C:\Mobicents-Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.2.2.619\standalone\deployments\restcomm‌​.war\/WEB-INF/sql/accounts.xml